# Get client user account using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cxf, autologin

I'm writing a web-application using Java. It's for company's internal use.

Now I want to get the client's account name, which is in *AD domain*, and send it to server.

What tech should I follow?

Or, is there any other idea to complete the auto-login?

> Consider this situation, the user login the windows system and open
>   our web app via browser, and the web app can know the user's windows
>   account name.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Impossible to answer without knowing what mechanisms you use for the login. Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: Thank you for your remind. We back-end team use cxf to build web service for front-end, and the front-end team uses spring-mvc.

Comment: And for authentication? Spring security perhaps?

Comment: Have not considered it yet... Our team are new to this problem.

Comment: Take a look at [waffle](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information, I guess the technology you are looking for is SPNEGO. This is the mechanism by which a browser on a windows machine can authenticate itself to a web-server transparently using the Kerberos keys present on the machine.

Here is a link to its Spring integration: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/

(I personally did not use the above Spring one, but used the Kerberos implementation that came with JDK 1.4)

The older non-secure version of windows transparent web-authentication used to be NTLM, but that shouldn't be supported anymore.